# Why do my tool tips appear far away from the mouse coordinates?

Tags: delphi, hint, tdbgrid, mouse-coordinates

I want to show a hint as the user moves the mouse over a `TDbStringGrid`. It almost works, but the hint shows high and to the left.

In my `OnMouseMove`, I receive X & Y, which I think are abosulte screen corrdinates, but I can use `dbGrid.MouseCoord(X, Y)` to get a point within the DB grid.

When I show my hint using `Application.ActivateHint()`, it is placed high and to the left.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try to use the [`ClientToScreen`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ClientToScreen) method to convert the control's relative coordinates to screen coordinates since [`ActivateHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ActivateHint) uses screen coordinates and events like [`OnMouseMove`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnMouseMove) receives control relative ones. In code, it might look like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DbStringGrid1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  ScreenRelativePoint: TPoint;
begin
  ScreenRelativePoint := (Sender as TControl).ClientToScreen(Point(X, Y));
  Application.ActivateHint(ScreenRelativePoint);
end;
```